# Meteor: Can I copy third party login emails to the root emails key in user document?

Tags: meteor

I have a collaboration app, which depends on the user having a unique username or email.

I am planning on using Google as a third party login.

I've tested it and I notice when I login with google account the email is available under the services key, but no email key or username key exists.

So what I have done is in the Accounts.onCreateUser function I extract the email address and manually create the emails key with address and verified keys like a user would have if they normally signed up.

Like this

```
Accounts.onCreateUser (options,user) ->

  unless user.emails?

    emailData = 
      address: determineEmail(user) * this gets [user.services.google.email]
      verified: false

    user.emails = []
    user.emails.push emailData

  if options.profile?
    if options.profile.name?
      nameArr = options.profile.name.split(" ")
      firstName = nameArr[0]
      lastName = nameArr[1]

      options.profile.firstName = firstName
      options.profile.lastName = lastName

    user.profile = options.profile

  user
```

So I am extracting the email from google services and make it so the email is available at Meteor.user().emails[0].address

This is because I use `Meteor.user().emails[0].address` throughout my app.

Will this cause any issues though? I've tested it in a limited fashion and it seems to be ok, but are there any concerns I have not considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `accounts-password` package ever gets added to your app (either directly by you or as a dependency of another package you add), then:

1. `Accounts.createUser()` will fail for that email address. If you eventually want to allow the user to login with either Google *or* a password, this might be confusing for the user, since the UI would probably treat them like they'd forgotten a password that they never had.
2. An attacker will be able to cause the server to send "reset password" emails to the email address.
3. An attacker will be able to check whether a user with that email address has an account in your app (by calling Accounts.createUser() and seeing whether it fails). The seriousness of such a privacy violation is app dependent.

If any of those things matter to you, you might want to check out [splendido:accounts-emails-field](https://atmospherejs.com/splendido/accounts-emails-field) as [Mark Uretsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5084201/mark-uretsky) mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this package useful it tries to keep all emails from all different sources into one place It's really useful

> This is a Meteor package which maintains the `registered_emails` array
>   field inside the user object up to date with any account service email
>   used by the user to login into the application.

https://atmospherejs.com/splendido/accounts-emails-field